# Is it OK to ask a question if I don't really have a problem?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Is it okay to ask a programming question on Stack Overflow even if I don't actually have a problem I need help with, but I think the question will help people who encounter the same problem in the future?

Comment: Do you mean answering your own question?

Comment: No, I mean just asking a question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my experience, it's generally not a good idea.

If you don't actually have the problem, you tend to be unable to answer any follow-up and clarification questions - and judge whether an answer actually solves the problem, and how well.